# CGGeometry Extension - Override CGRectMake

Tags: swift, core-graphics, cgrect

I'm trying to extend the CGGeometry class (or is it a struct?). I've tried importing `UIKit`, `CoreGraphics`, `CoreGraphics.CGGeometry`, and even `Foundation` but I keep getting "Use of undeclared type CGGeometry".

This is my actual extension, just trying to override `CGRectMake()` for starters. Is it even possible to override CGGeometry?

```
extension CGGeometry {
    override func CGRectMake() {

    }
}
```

Comment: `CGGeometry` is not a thing and it doesn't make sense to override `CGRectMake`. What do you want to achieve?

Comment: are you sure? https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/GraphicsImaging/Reference/CGGeometry/index.html

Comment: I'm trying to create like a RectMakeWithSizeCenteredInRect method because I use it a ton rn and I'm trying to clean up my code

Comment: just create your own function that return CGRect and use it in your code

Answer (score 0, accepted):

CGGeometry is not a class actually neither a struct, the file is called CGGeometry where the defenitions of geometric primitives are defined, so you cannot override it.

Answer (score 0):

CGGeometry is a C header that provides inline C functions bridged to Swift.  Swift provides a new `CGRect()` initializer as an alternative to using the old inline C function `CGRectMake()`.  Consider extending `CGRect` and creating your own initializer:

```
extension CGRect {

    init(centeredInRect: CGRect) {
        self = // logic here
    }
}
```